# CGAL - Triangulate Mesh, Return Face to Face Mapping?

Tags: c++, cgal, triangulation

I have a quad mesh which I want to triangulate, but I also would like to have a mapping which records which quads of the original mesh have become which triangles on the resultant mesh.

Obviously I am aware of the

```
CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::triangulate_faces(mesh);
```

function. But I was wondering via the NamedParameters if it is possible to return this information?

Answer (score 0):

This functionality is NOT provided, but it would be rather straightforward to add it. In what context do you use it (homework, another open source project, company,...?), what is your time frame, ....

Let me add that I added the functionality in a [github PR](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/3268). It is not necessarily the final version, as it has to go through the CGAL review process first. Maybe I can even get feedback from you.

Have a look at the [example](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/3268/commits/f55da7bfe088e517fa7e57d2f9f40619053e411f#diff-67359b7af5f6c36e1294014d9497e95a) where I copy the non-triangle mesh, and while I copy I create a face to face map. This one is then passed to the visitor that updates the map.

It is

Comment: As part of some academic research, I am trying to optimize my code base and I have been converting all my mesh operations over to using CGAL based operations. As part of this I have a quad mesh, which I triangulate in order to run some optimization algorithms (which alters position and structure of the mesh). Finally, I need to convert that back to the original quad mesh, so I need to know which quads became which triangles, then I do the book-keeping, before converting back.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response, for some reason stack overflow didn't notify you had replied. Thank you for added the required code, I will check it out.